# Displaying various medias in the same view

Tags: android, performance, video, photo

I have an activity with a `RecyclerView`. This `RecyclerView` is populated dynamically via calls to a webservice (featuring endless scrolling, pull to refresh etc..).
If one item is a photo I just want to display it, and if it's a video, i want to have some kind of `MediaController` to be able to play it directly from the list.
I already achieved something that looks like what I want with this layout (here it's simplified) :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
          android:layout_marginBottom="7dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/field_picture"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/field_video"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my `RecyclerView.Adapter` i do the following :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
  if (event.isVideo) {
      viewHolder.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      // loading video here
  }
  else {
      viewHolder.vid.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      // loading photo here (Glide is used to achieve this)
  }
}
```

but this seem to cause some clipping problems sometimes, and I wander if i'm not using a bad practise here.
So the question is the following : what is the best way to achieve what i want to do in term of performance (my scrolling has to be really fluid) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can create two different layouts (one with imageView and one with videoView) and two view holders in your custom adapter. like that :

```
public class MultipleViewTypesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO  = 0;
private static final int VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;

class ViewHolderVideo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
}

class ViewHolderImage extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ...
}

@Override
int getItemViewType(int position) {
   if (event.isVideo) {
     return VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO;
   }
   else {
     return VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE;
   }
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    switch (viewType) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO:
          View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item_video, parent, false); 
          return new ViewHolderVideo(v);
        case VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE: 
          View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_item_image, parent, false); 
          return new ViewHolderImage(v);
        ...
    }
}

@Override
public void bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_VIDEO:
            ViewHolderVideo viewHolderVideo = (ViewHolderVideo)holder;
            ...
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE:
            ViewHolderImage viewHolderImage = (ViewHolderSecond)holder;
            ...
            break;
        ...
    }
}
}
```

I hope it will help.

Comment: that worked fine, i just tweaked it a little bit with an abstract class for my different ViewHolders ! thx